# Two quick questions about domainUpDown c#

Tags: c#

Good morning,
I've noticed that when using a `DomainUpDown` ([DomainUpDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.domainupdown?view=netframework-4.8)), when scrolling the mouse wheel a notch, items are scrolled to their extreme.

For example:

Items in the `DomainUpDown` :

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4

The domain is on 1, I scroll my mouse down a notch and we land on 4.

My second question is is it possible to activate the control, but without being able to select the inside because currently, when it is in readOnly, I can still scroll through the elements but I can still select them.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check your mouse scroll speed ? Did you check `CanSelect` ?

Comment: that's not the mistake, that's for sure

Comment: You do want to provide some code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to go further.